# Why the word Applet is Striken in netbeans?

Tags: java, applet

when I tried to extend Applet in netbeans, the word Applet is striked. I have also imported the required packages. can anybody explain why this is happening and how do i stop this?

Comment: you don't stop it. It became deprecated over a decade ago. it was replaced by JApplet, which you shouldn't use neither, since browsers no longer support applets.

Comment: Java applets were **deprecated** since Java 9 in 2017 and **removed** from Java SE 11 (18.9), released in September 2018.

Comment: @PM77-1 's comment is probably already the answer.

Comment: Tell your instructor their curriculum is outdated and no longer possible to use. This is [**not** new](https://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). That link is seven years old!

Answer (score 1):

Stricken means it is deprecated, and it will probably tell you so if you hover it in your IDE.

Deprecated packages are usually very old and have replacements. They aren't removed immediately from the library because that would break old code. They're not maintained and will be removed with future versions of java. If you're following some sort of tutorial to learn the language, it is likely very old.